# Where is the JavaDoc for QueueConfiguration?

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I explore the [ActiveMQ Artemis Documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/client/ClientSession.html#createQueue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-) and want to use the method `createQueue` to dynamically create queues. However, I can't find the right one which is not tagged with `@Deprecated`. The only one which was not deprecated is this one:

```java
createQueue(QueueConfiguration queueConfiguration)
```

However, I get a 404 if I want to know what `QueueConfiguration` needs.

Can anybody tell me where I can find the JavaDoc for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.QueueConfiguration` is in the `artemis-commons` module rather than the `artemis-core-client` module like most of the other client classes, and it appears that the JavaDoc for that module is not published during the release process. Please refer to the [source code itself](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-commons/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/QueueConfiguration.java).